# JavaScript puzzling output

Tags: javascript, prototype, javascript-objects

Consider the code below. The `d1` object so created, does not have `name` property but why ? However, if I remove the setting of prototype as function object, things works fine. please note that below code is deliberately written like that to test how JS reacts !

```
function Dog(name){

  this.name = name;

}

// Notice that I am  putting function object as prototype 
Dog.prototype = function(){}

var d1 = new Dog("happy");
console.log(d1.name); //gives empty string
console.dir(d1); // `d1` does not have name property 
console.log(d1 instanceof Dog);// returns true ??
```

Comment: By doing this, you are destroying the constructor property

Comment: You should remove `Dog.prototype = function(){}` it resets everything.

Comment: "*I am  putting function object as prototype*" - well, don't do that.

Comment: @Chris , how is my Dog object getting created but without `name` property ?

Comment: @Bergi , i was just playing with JS but now this output explanation I am not able to logically link

Comment: @Number945 Your object is created using Object.prototype.constructor
If you set your prototype to something that doesnt have a constructor...it will not work

Comment: I don't think the duplicate target is relevant enough

Comment: Wow, I found two exact duplicates for this :-) @Chris it is. The second one I added has a better explanation though

Comment: @Bergi, I understood that `d1` is inheriting from the new prototype and since it is anonymous function it has no `name` property and hence, the property is printed as undefined. But what happened to my `this.name =name`. After all `d1 instanceof Dog` returns true (and this another thing puzzling to me)

Comment: @Number945 Actually the anonymous function *does* have a `.name` property, it's just the empty string (not `undefined` - what browser (version) where you using when you got that?).

Comment: @Bergi , I ran that in chrome Version 79.0.3945.130 (Official Build) (64-bit). My bad I am getting empty string only ! Edited the code example. But why it is not taking name from constructor ?

Comment: @Number945 See the explanation in the duplicates, and use strict mode.